# What does this error code mean ( code attached)

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

ERROR:The method onCancel() of type SoftKeyboard must override a superclass method  SoftKeyboard.java   /EmotePractice/src/com/emote    line 691    Java Problem

Superclass?? I thought @Override was meant to catch errors made with grammar, why is it saying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the superclass you're overriding has a method called `onCancel()`, with no parameters and `void` return type? If the answer is no, try removing the `@Override` annotation and see if it works for you.

The `@Override` annotation is used for indicating that the method is overriding an identically declared method in a superclass. From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html):

> @Override Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a superclass. If a method is annotated with this annotation type but does not override a superclass method, compilers are required to generate an error message.

Comment: @VictoriaC You're welcome! If this answer was helpful for you, please consider accepting it (click the check mark to its left)

Answer (score 0):

The block of code you put it probably has some errors. For example, this SoftKeyboard might have other functions which must be overriden or perhaps defined in the first place, so this would be an error that goes away automatically once those other conditions are met. Either way, please paste more of the contextual code so that we can better isolate the issue.

BTW the @Override doesn't catch errors made with grammar but rather literally overrides the super classes predefined method.

Comment: I removed the override and the errors went away thank you for correcting me on what @override does I read on a blogspot that it was mainly to catch mistakes of grammer as if the computer says hey we cant continue on because youve mis-spelled.... ( thats literally the example that was given) Thank you for your feedback!! Im a newbie!!

Comment: Glad your code compiled. Be sure to run it and test to ensure that oncancel code gets executed as expected.

Comment: I will I have a strange feeling that I will be back with a question pertaining to oncancel .... :(